# How to investigate PHP crash in Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I have written a piece of code which is crashing Apache process. I would like to know if there is any way I can get any helpful information logged anywhere or if there is any way at all I can investigate what happened?

The code which is crashing:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$stmtQuery = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ?, 'name'");
$stmtQuery->bind_result($id, $name);

$stmtQuery->attr_set(MYSQLI_STMT_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE, MYSQLI_CURSOR_TYPE_READ_ONLY);
$stmtQuery->bind_param('i', $i);
$stmtQuery->execute();
$stmtQuery->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

There is nothing in PHP error_log.
In Apache error_log all I see is:

> [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8212:tid 652] AH00428: Parent: child process 20232 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.

I don't know what this status means, and I am looking for more insightful crash report.

Comment: You could use Blackfire. Its an debugger tool which can help you identify this.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138269/apache-error-notice-parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477-res

Comment: Yes, that was the first google result. The solution says to increase stack size of Apache process, but if I triggered seg fault in PHP I would like to know why it happened. I was hoping that Apache would save some crash logs somewhere, but I can't find any.

Comment: I was reading through a few results here and it the "fixes" people suggest for it vary pretty wildly. I haven't found anything yet about how to  properly diagnose the reason for the crash, which I agree seems much more useful.

Comment: Wow, there are tons of Q&A about this. I'm surprised I've never encountered it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Think what you're looking for is `strace`:

```
strace -f $(pidof php5-fpm | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)/\-p \1/g')
```

Source: [Debugging Stuck PHP-FPM Process With Strace](https://shubhamjain.co/2015/09/10/debugging-stuck-php-fpm-process-with-strace/)

MPM [worker](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html) & [prefork](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html) might have different process names.

This would show the threading model: `httpd -V | grep MPM`

It might be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643131/how-strace-php-fpm-process) question; also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138269/apache-error-notice-parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477-res) seems related ...

---

It crashes because the value of [ThreadStackSize](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#threadstacksize) had been exceeded -

likely caused due to cluelessly attempting to allocate a cursor window ...

`mod_mysqli` is at fault and the thread is being killed for the sake of stability.